# Declared javascript object set to null values

Tags: javascript, object

It's a simple question i have, I have a javascript object which is declared like this -

```
   adminID = {"Name": "","AdminId": ""}
```

At a later point in the code i assign it some values -

```
  adminID = {"Name": "xyzabc","AdminId": "123123"}
```

Now, how can i assign the values back to null so my object looks like

```
  adminID = {"Name": "","AdminId": ""}
```

Is there a smarter way to do it or should i specify all the keys to null individually.

Cheers!

Comment: Do you want `null` as in your description or `""` (empty string) as in your code sample?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'd do it like this in JavaScript:

```
for(var p in adminID)
    if(adminID.hasOwnProperty(p))
        adminID[p] = '';
```

Answer (score 3):

Ruby version

Here is one way

```
adminID.each {|k,v| adminID[k] = ""}
```

Here is another

```
adminID.keys.each {|k| adminID[k] = ""}
```

Javascript version

```
for(var i in adminID) { adminID[i] = ""}
```

Comment: Thanks! Sorry i just realized i had implemented that in a javascript. How can I achieve the same in javascript.

Comment: I added a js version of my code as well. I think @mu's version is more robust.

Comment: Thank a lot, for the js version!

Answer (score 1):

```
adminID.each_key {|key| adminID[key] = ''}
```

Comment: That's why I gave you an up-vote and went to the OP for some clarification. You answered what they asked rather than what they meant, or something like that. Hooray for confusion!